# How to set default parent property from child?

Tags: java, lombok

Assume that I have two classes entitled Child1 and Child2 that inherits from Parent class. As you can see below, all class is marked with
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@superBuilder
annotations.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@superBuilder
class Parent{   
    Integer id;   
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    String type;   
}


@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@superBuilder
class Child1 extends Parent{   
    // type = child1
} 

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@superBuilder
class Child2 extends Parent{   
    // type = child2
}
```

How can I set the type field defined in parent by default in child classes?

Comment: Is `type` initialised to something in `Parent`? Otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Comment: I think you need to initialize in `Parent` like `final String type = "some value";`

Comment: You are right, I just put final to emphasize this field's value should only be assigned on initialization of child @Sweeper

Comment: @Hamed That's... not what `final` means. "this field's value should only be assigned on initialization of child" is not something you can enforce in Java.

Comment: Yes, I know. I don't want this field to be change runtime.

Comment: @Sweeper can you suggest any solution to do so? Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check example

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@superBuilder
@MappedSuperclas
abstract  class Parent{   
    Integer id;   
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    String type;   
}


 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @superBuilder
 @AttributeOverride(name="type", 
column=@Column(name="child1_column_type_name", columnDefinition="String default your_default_value", insertable=false))
 class Child1 extends Parent{   
     // type = child1
 } 

 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @superBuilder
@AttributeOverride(name="type", 
column=@Column(name="child2_column_type_name", 
 columnDefinition="String  default your_default_value", insertable=false))
 class Child2 extends Parent{   
     // type = child2
 }
```

Comment: how can I set the value?

Comment: No @AttributeOverride has other parameters other than column name

Comment: I couldn't find any parameter to set the value, please post it in the answer, So I can check the solution as solved.

Comment: You changed the column name. what about its value? I'm looking for setting value in child classes.

Comment: default value ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232550/discussion-between-hamed-and-zaur).

Comment: Not working please read this is documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e714